# Which condition has to be met to execute this if branch

Tags: disassembly, assembly, debuggers, windbg

Right now I am playing around with a little *training* application I found on [OpenSecurityTraining](http://opensecuritytraining.info/).

So, I analyzed this code and I think I understand this pretty well. The only thing I don't get is the `cmp` and `je` at lines `0x004010e3` and `0x004010e7` which seem to be some `if` conditions. But, I cannot figure out which condition should be met to take the jump instruction.

My workaround was to manipulate `eip` when the `cmp` line was executed. But, my question is what condition has to be set to take the `je` instruction ?

```
004010e0 55              push    ebp
004010e1 8bec            mov     ebp,esp
004010e3 837d0803        cmp     dword ptr [ebp+8],3
004010e7 7412            je      mystery!main+0x1b (004010fb)
004010e9 6834404200      push    offset mystery!__rtc_tzz <PERF> (mystery+0x24034) (00424034)
004010ee e81c040000      call    mystery!printf (0040150f)
004010f3 83c404          add     esp,4
004010f6 83c8ff          or      eax,0FFFFFFFFh
004010f9 eb0b            jmp     mystery!main+0x26 (00401106)
004010fb e80affffff      call    mystery!mystery_function+0xffffffff`ffffffea (0040100a)
00401100 eb02            jmp     mystery!main+0x24 (00401104)
00401102 eb02            jmp     mystery!main+0x26 (00401106)
00401104 33c0            xor     eax,eax
00401106 5d              pop     ebp
00401107 c3              ret
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extended Base Pointer, as the name suggests, is usually used as a frame pointer. That, among other things, means that it's used to access function parameters and local variables. If you think about how stack works, you can conclude the following:

- local variables will be on the negative offset from the base pointer
- address in the frame pointer will be the location of the previous function's frame pointer
- address at the +4 offset from EBP will be the return address
- offsets greater than 4 are function parameters

That being said, ebp+8 is usually the first function argument. The compare instruction in this case compares the value of the first function parameter to 3. If those are equal (`je` instruction is `jump if equal`) the conditional jump will be executed.

Answer (score 3):

`dword ptr [val]` is exactly, what it says: **A 32bit pointer to value**. As to how `cmp`, `je` and all the other instructions work, I recommend the reading of the [Intel Manual](http://www.intel.com/Assets/en_US/PDF/manual/253666.pdf).